# Trigger function by specifying function name

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, triggers

I'm building a website that will send an email notification when certain actions are completed. As of right now, I've got a generic notification function that is called in certain areas with parameters to reference a database record containing the message, etc.

I'd like to know if there is any way to make a trigger like this dynamic so adding/removing triggers in different areas of the website doesn't require codebehind changes. I was thinking something with reflection and the namespace/function to call the trigger from loaded from the database, but I would imagine that would have a significant performance impact.

Comment: What makes you think that there would be `a significant performance impact`?

Comment: I suppose my concerns stemmed from the fact that I do not know how to implement a proper solution via reflection and assumed that there would be a substantial number of additional checks to see which functions should execute a trigger. Thinking about it more, I can see that my concerns are probably irrational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection really does not have that big of a performance impact, especially when you factor in caching the function pointers after the first time you do a lookup.

This is a simple spike, may not compile or work, but should get you on the right path:

```
var type = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
var parser = type.GetMethod("Parse");
Console.WriteLine(parser.Invoke(null, "2012-01-01 12:00"));
```

Parser is a MethodInfo object, and can be cached to be used later. Calling invoke is no worse performant than calling `DateTime.Parse` directly. If I had to guess, the slowest call is to Type.GetType, even then though we are not talking about a lot of time, definitely on the ms scale.

If you can give a little more information too, it's possible someone can point you in a better direction even. Maybe a little DI or IoC information is pertinent.

Comment: `Calling invoke is no worse performant than calling DateTime.Parse directly.` Have you tried it? I did and `Invoke` is 2x slower. But this doesn't mean @Eclyps19 should avoid using reflection

Comment: @L.B on what scale? seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds? Let me rephrase slightly, s/he is writing a web application, reflection should be the least of their worries when it comes to performance.

Comment: `you are writing a web application, reflection should be the least of your worries when it comes to performance` Yes I say the same. But I just wanted to point out that reflection is always slower than direct call. Try and see

Comment: `on what scale? seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds?` I said 2x times. choose whatever scale you want

Comment: @L.B Fair enough, maybe should have been clearly. In my defense, performant is relative, and I never said it would be faster :) As far as scale, that's not fair. 2 seconds is a big deal, 200 ns, I wouldn't even consider that slower.